# Как привязать звук к перелистыванию ViewPager2?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, аудио, recyclerviewadapter

Создал объект SoundPool. Загрузил в него звук. При каком-либо событии (например, нажатие кнопки) могу воспроизвести этот звук. В программе используется ViewPager2 и RecyclerView.Adapter для его подключения к данным. Мне нужно, чтобы при каждом перелистывании страницы ViewPager2 воспроизводился звук, который я уже загрузил. Я не могу понять на какое событие повесить воспроизведение для того, чтобы воспроизведение начиналось при каждом перелистывании? Или это решается как-то по-другому?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

За перелистыванием ViewPager2 следит registerOnPageChangeCallback. Следующий код выполняет всё необходимое

```
viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        super.onPageSelected(position);
            // код для выполнения
        }
    });
```